# Error Send Mail From Gmail

Tags: c#, email, gmail, smtpclient

Plz help I don't know solve this problem, the error msg I uploaded in this image
I need help ??? 
[the error description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O63eR.png)

[Code C#](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nt9Xn.png)

Comment: Please paste code here, And translate the error message to English if you desire any helpful response from anyone in the community

Comment: You can't use network credentials with a gmail account.  The same code that works with outlook will not work with gmail.  Go to gmail website and look for sample code at the gmail.com mail site.  There was a change between Net 3.5 and Net 4.0 for default settings for NetworkCredentails so code that worked in Net 3.5 doesn't always work with Net4.0. NetworkCredentials uses your login account on your PC which has nothing to do with the credentials for your gmail account.  NetworkCredentials only works when the email server like Outlook is using the same password that you use to login on your PC.

Comment: Post code and output, not links.

Comment: use cleint.UseDefaultCredentials = false.  and settings on following webpage..Port 587 will automatically implement TLS : https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1692342?hl=en&ref_topic=3410139#ts=2777542

Answer (score 0):

Error authentication. Try this:

```
client.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

And check your gmail inbox if you are setting any security.